# How do I align these 3 divs and a span?

Tags: html, css

You can see the implementation here: http://jsfiddle.net/kqKfK/

I am trying to get everything in one line - with the span "2-up" at the far right. It would also be nice if each of the internal divs are equally spaced amongst themselves.

Edit: This is how I want it to look:

[image]

Edit 2: This is how it looks after the implementation of Kyle's suggestion. I would like for it to be aligned properly:

[image]

Edit 3: This is how it looks after Kyle's second implementation.

[image]

Comment: Could you make a picture of how you want it to look? It's not entirely clear.

Comment: Replace the squares with the numbers for this example. But you get the idea of how it should look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float them left:

```
#viewbar div
{
    float: left;
}
```

[Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/kqKfK/3/)

---

```
#viewbar div
{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

[Updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/kqKfK/13/). Changed a few things in your original code too.

---

After your comment, try this:

```
#viewbar div
{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    background-image: url(path/to/file.png);
    background-position: center;
}
```

[Another example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/kqKfK/15/).

---

After you provided the full example, I came up with this, looks very much like the screenshot you posted.

[Click here to see my example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/d6MhA/4/). I changed a lot of things, including equal heights on each div, adding margins and padding :)

Comment: I think you are the closest to how I want it to look. However, one issue I am having now is that when I substitute the numbers for `backgrounds` of the div, they are now hugging the left side of the internal divs. Look at my question, I am going to post a screenshot of the updated version right now.

Comment: Ok, just one question, are the images `<img>` tags or background images?

Comment: background images of each of the internal divs. Everything else is identical to your code.

Comment: Almost there. I added an updated screenshot to the post to show what it looks like now. To be sure...each of the internal `divs` i.e. `#two-up-icon`, `#three-up-icon`, `#four-up-icon` rather than one div background like you did for `#viewbar div`. However, I just added `background-position: center;` to the `#viewbar div`, and the outcome is in the updated image. Given that you have width of 25% in `#viewbar div` should I get rid of the individual widths of each of the `#two-up-icon`, `#three-up-icon`, etc ?

Comment: No, remove the 25% width. I didn't realise that you had differing lengths of image in the first example, see what happens when 25% is removed.

Comment: Scratch that question about the width. I took out all the individual width elements and put `width: 25%; height: 17px;` in the `#viewbar div`. But that hasn't worked.

Comment: Just saw your update. Will try that and let you know. I did it the opposite way around.

Comment: Wow....it looks even worse. Should I post a screenshot of that, or do you have an idea ? Fun? HAH!! Not in the least. But at least it is better than Rails issues - maybe because I understand CSS better :)

Comment: Can you give access to the page you're testing on? It would be much easier to help you with the full example :)

Comment: Hrmm....kinda hard to do that. Haven't put anything on a public server - especially not one you could get the source code of. Don't have that facility now :( Hrmm...maybe I can put the background images online and just update the fiddle with the paths of those images and give a more accurate fiddle. Would that work ?

Comment: Last example provided, should be what you want now :)

Comment: Sweeet dude!!!! Thanks very much. I REALLLY appreciate. It was pretty hideous before. Very JS heavy. Now it is nice and light with CSS :) THANKS DUDE!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.compv-navbar {    
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #f9f4c0;
    height: 23px;
    width: 220px;
    border: 1px solid #c97d7d;
    word-spacing: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin: 0 auto 5px;    /* top, right, bottom, left */        
    padding: 5px 0px 7px 0px;     /* top, right, bottom, left */    
    text-align: center;
}

#two-up-icon {
    width: 40px;
    height: 17px;
    float: left;
}

#two-up-icon:hover {
    color: #ddd;
    cursor: pointer;    
}

#three-up-icon {
    width: 40px;
    height: 15px;   
    float: left;
}

#three-up-icon:hover {
    color: #ddd;
    cursor: pointer;    
}

#four-up-icon {
    width: 40px;
    height: 15px;  
    float: left;
}

#four-up-icon:hover {
    color: #ddd;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.view_name {
    font-family: "Helvetica", serif;
    color: #f9f4c0;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    word-spacing: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    background: #1a1a1a;    
    padding: 1px 3px 1px 3px; /* top, right, bottom, left */        
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kqKfK/10/

Comment: Can you explain what you did ? Did you just add float properties to each ?

Comment: I added float to each of two-up-icon, three-up-icon and four-up-icon, made the widths a constant of 40px, added float and margin properties to view_name. :)

Answer (score 2):

just add one more style:

```
.compv-navbar div { float: left; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

One line of CSS:

```
#viewbar div, #viewbar span { width: 25%; float: left; }
```

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/kqKfK/2/

Edit: By the way, `alt` is only for images, other elements should use the `title` attribute instead.

<strike>Edit II: if you have anything after that `div`, put such thing before to clear the "floatness":</strike>

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Comment: The span won't accept width unless `display: block;` is declared.

Comment: @Kyle as far as I can see, making it float also make it block level element, gave it background and it has the proper width assigned. http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/kqKfK/12/

Comment: Oh, of course you're right! Forgot that for a conveniently long enough amount of time to make me comment something wrong on your answer :) Excuse me :)

Comment: Shadow Wizard, I just updated my post with an image of how I want it to look. Not sure what you mean by your second edit. Do you mind using my code and applying your changes - so I can see it within the context of my code. Thanks

Comment: @marc disregard the second edit, it's something I remembered from long time ago but just now tested in Chrome/IE8 and it's not relevant anymore. Regarding the image looks like Kyle is on the correct path no need for two. :)

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for trying though :)